# Go to another activity when all fields are not empty

Tags: android, methods, interface, android-lifecycle

I have **1 activity** and **3 fragments** in this activity.

In 3 fragments I have booleans returning true when checkbox is checked or edittext is not empty..

I want to unable button when editTexts are not empty and my checkbox is checked..

When I added something like sexMan.isChecked() to method EditTextCompleted()
my app crushing....

So how can I connects this conditions in one place?

Checkbox Listener

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (isChecked){
        mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.sexChecked(true);
        switch (buttonView.getId()){

            case R.id.sexMan:
                mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.sex(BmrCalculation.SEX_MAN);
                sexMan.setChecked(true);
                sexWoman.setChecked(false);
                break;

            case R.id.sexWoman:
                sexMan.setChecked(false);
                sexWoman.setChecked(true);
                mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.sex(BmrCalculation.SEX_WOMAN);
                break;
```

Edit Text listener

@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

```
    if ( s == weightEditText.getEditableText()){
        mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.getweight(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
        mWeight = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    } else if ( s == heightEditText.getEditableText()) {
        mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.getheight(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
        mHeight = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    } else if ( s == ageEditText.getEditableText()){
        mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.getage(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
        mAge = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    }

    if ( (!(weightEditText.getEditableText().toString().equals("")) && !(heightEditText.getEditableText().toString().equals("")) && !(ageEditText.getEditableText().toString().equals("")))) {
        mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.editTextComplete(true);
    } else {
        mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.editTextComplete(false);
    }

}
```

Interface

```
public interface sendInfoFromBmrFragment {

        public void getheight(int height);
        public void getweight(int weight);
        public void getage(int age);
        public void editTextComplete(boolean editTextComplete);
        public void sex(String sex);

    }
```

Comment: Hard to say which method when we don't see your code.

Comment: @KristyWelsh code added

Comment: Soo.. I changed logic.. meybe its not super optimal but its working.. I changed checkboxes to be disable at start.. then deleted condition " mSendInfoFromBmrFragment.editTextComplete(true); " and replaced with myChecbox.setEnabled(true) and then if my checbox is selected im enabling button to go another acitivty.

Answer (score 1):

For the Radio Buttons you can declare an array if you know their number and they are static, do this as follow:

```
 public Boolean AllRadiosAreChecked;
 private Boolean Checked[] = 
  {
      false, // sexMan is checked ?
      false   // sexWoman is checked ?
   };
```

Then, in the same activity ovverride the OnCheckedChanged

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (isChecked){
        switch (buttonView.getId()){

            case R.id.sexMan:
                 Checked[0]=true;
                 break;

            case R.id.sexWoman:
                Checked[1]=true;
                break;
```

Then you check anywhere you want if all Radio Buttons are checked:

```
                AllRadiosAreChecked=true;
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                {
                    if (!Checked[i])
                    {
                        AllRadiosAreChecked= false;
                    }
                }
                if(!AllRadiosAreChecked){

                    // NOT all radio buttons are checked
                }
                else{
              // All radio buttons are checked enter code here

                }
```

This conditions in the array must be declared to group radios.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can add callbacks to your checkboxes and then they all are true you need call method in your parent activity (for example send in activity fragment ID and boolean value). To call method from activity you need to use the next code

```
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).yourMethod();
```

And then activity received all booleans from all fragment you need to change Button visibility.

Comment: Fragment sending booleand true when all EditTexts are completed.. But i also want connect conditions with checkbox

Answer (score 0):

If you have edittext you can add textchangelistener to it, if you have checkbox you can add listener of it, in listener you can check validation. Based on validation you can enable or disable the button for next activity. You can have that button to be static to access from other class.

In every listener you can call one public static method in which you will check all validation every time, if it satisfies then method will return true and you can enable button.

Comment: I know it.. but i want mix this conditions in one place then show one button if all is true.